# Are adding code samples invalid edits?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

Since when is adding the code that was originally a link an invalid edit?

Comment: I don't see a link in the question you mention. There is no evidence that this is the code the OP is trying to run.

Comment: Yeah that was a bad example. I have seen some questions where the code is linked and someone adds the code as an edit and it gets rejected. I don't have any examples that I can link to.

Comment: It's also often difficult to judge where a suggested edit comes from without a clear edit message. A suddenly appearing block of code, without a decent explanation, is something I would reject.

Comment: @ColeJohnson Well, if that's the case, then odds are it's an appropriate edit.  In many cases this is an issue of a poor revision comment though.  If the revision comment says, "adding code from the link to the question" it's much more likely to be approved than if it says "1029 characters added to body".

Comment: Since never. More reasonable to ask "Since when are edit reviews always right?" Also since never.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you paste in code that was from a link, it's worth making it **crystal** clear that's what you're doing in your description, otherwise a hasty reviewer might just see a bunch of new code and say no.

Adding code that was in a link should be accepted if it's clear from the edit description that that's what happened. A diligent reviewer would check that the two matched.

---

The example you first gave had no link in the original, and it very much appears the user who suggested it found that code themselves.

Suggested edits are for changing how well a question or answer says something, not for changing what they say, so sadly edits like [the one you originally linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1380521) count as changing too much and will be rejected.

With enough rep (2000) users can edit without being subject to review. (And should also be more familiar with what the community's expectations are.) With this rep we trust people more not to vandalise something, so there's more freedom, but also more responsibility.

For suggested edits, please improve grammar, phrasing and spelling, etc. throughout the post.

Reviewer's aren't expected ever to make a judgement about the content, so edits shouldn't change the content/overall meaning.

The edit description was

> Added sample code to help anyone quickly reproduce the problem. Also notice that not just the side toolbar, but everything else outside the top toolbar stops responding to mouse-over events when the overflow is visible.

That clearly falls into the category of an edit which changes too much or is an attempt to reply to or comment on the original. Those are standard reasons for rejecting edits.

Comment: Everything before your last edited in sentence doesn't really apply, because Cole isn't saying any old code example being edited in is appropriate.

Comment: @Servy but the example edit he links to does _not_ have a link to any code, as per [ChrisF's comment under the question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164754/adding-code-samples-are-invalid-edits/164755#comment480522_164754).

Comment: Which is why the OP removed the link and said in [this comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164754/adding-code-samples-are-invalid-edits/164755#comment480530_164754) to consider the hypothetical of what to do in the event someone does take code from a link and put it in the question.

Comment: @Servy Which is why I've continued to edit. The things I say are very relevant to the example, and something I think it's important to be said in the light of the example; I'll not delete them.

Answer (score 8):

It's going to be all about the edit comment here. I bring code and images inline all the time on sites where I don't have edit privs, and my comment is

> bringing code inline

(or image, obviousy) The reviewer can then see that a link has been removed and 20 lines of code has been added, and approve. An especially good reviewer can follow the link to see if I brought in the right code. These edits of mine are always approved.

But if the comment is

> added 453 characters in body

Then (switching to my reviewer hat) I would reject that edit.

Comment: It didn't say "added 453 characters in body", it said "Added sample code to help anyone quickly reproduce the problem. Also notice that not just the side toolbar, but everything else outside the top toolbar stops responding to mouse-over events when the overflow is visible".

Comment: ah, I don't have a link to the specific edit in question, that's a detailed one, but starting "Added sample code (from link) to help..." or "Brought sample code from link inline to help..." would be better still.

Comment: You're quite right.